# Return type of resource color android?

Tags: java, android, colors

What is the return type of something starting with `R` like a color in Android.

For instance, `R.color.black`, I want to create a helper function like

```
public RETURN_TYPE getColor(){

   return R.color.black;

}
```

What is the `RETURN_TYPE` supposed to be?

Comment: You can see from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color) that the return type is int

Answer (score 1):

I think the value behind R.color.black is an integer.

I found this info in the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color).

Hope my answer was helpfull.